# Get device resolution in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Is there a way to get the device resolution of a Windows 10 Device? I mean, the resolution given by the hardware (like 1920x1200 or 1366x768), not the current window resolution.

Comment: `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds` only gives the resolution of the resizeable app window. I searched a way, to find the "real" resolution of the display.

Comment: Check the accepted answer in the link. Yes it does.

Comment: I've adopted the unchanged three lines of code to my app. It gives only the resolution of the current window.

Comment: Did you call it right after `Window.Current.Activate();`?

Comment: Ohh, sorry. You are right, I've overlooked this. Now it works perfect